# How to fit a linear regression in R with a fixed negative intercept?

Tags: r, regression

Background: Species richness scales to the negative -0.75 of body weight. However, when I fit my data, I get a value of 0.57. A friend told me that the summary(lm) results prints the 'best fit' slope of the data. Nevertheless, I'm wondering if I can create a regression plot wherein I force the slope to be -0.75 like the literature.

My code is:

## y value

log.nspecies.dec = c(3.05, 2.95, 2.97, 2.98, 2.84, 2.85, 2.83, 2.71, 2.64, 2.62, 2.58, 2.37,
2.26, 2.17, 2.00, 1.88, 1.75, 1.62, 1.36, 1.30, 1.08, 1.20, 0.90, 0.30, 0.70,
0.30, 0.48, 0.00, 0.30, 0.00)

## x value

logbio.dec = c(2.1, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7, 2.9, 3.1, 3.3, 3.7, 3.9, 4.1, 4.3, 4.5, 4.7, 4.9, 5.1,
5.3, 5.5, 5.7, 5.9, 6.1, 6.3, 6.5, 6.7, 6.9, 7.1, 7.3, 7.5, 7.7, 7.9)

## plot a barplot and superimpose a regression line

## name the y variables with the x

names(log.nspecies.dec) = logbio.dec

## order the y variables

log.nspecies.dec = log.nspecies.dec[order (as.numeric(names(log.nspecies.dec)))]

## do the barplot

xpos = barplot(log.nspecies.dec, las = 2, space = 0)

lm.fit = lm(log.nspecies.dec ~ as.numeric(names(log.nspecies.dec)))
summary(lm.fit)

y.init = lm.fit$coefficients[2] * as.numeric(names(log.nspecies.dec))[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJobc.jpg) + 
  lm.fit$coefficients[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJobc.jpg)

y.end = lm.fit$coefficients[2] * as.numeric(names(log.nspecies.dec))[length(log.nspecies.dec)] +
  lm.fit$coefficients[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJobc.jpg)

segments(xpos[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJobc.jpg), y.init, xpos [length(xpos)], y.end, lwd = 2, col = 'red')

title(main = 'ln Number of species ~ lm Weight')

coef(lm.fit)

gives a result wherein the slope is 0.57. How do I force the slope to -0.75? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offset` to fix the y-intercept at a negative value. For example

```
## Example data
x = 1:10
y = -2 + 2* x

# Fit the model
(m = lm(y ~ 0 + x, offset = rep(-2, length(y))))


#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x, offset = rep(-2, length(y)))

#Coefficients:
#x  
#2
```

The output correctly identifies the gradient as 2.

The reason your code doesn't work is that you are using `abline()`. Looking at `?abline`, it states that to draw the line it will in turn call `coef(MODEL)`. When you use offset, the `coef` function doesn't return the y-intercept.

```
R> coef(m)
x 
2
```

Hence `abline` draws the wrong line.

---

If the intercept is changed, the code still works

```
x = 1:10
y = 2 + 2*x
lm(y ~ 0 + x, offset = rep(2, length(y)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, when I tried this code the intercept was not -0.75, it became +0.46;  a positive slope that deviated from the literature. Moreover, when you used the coef in your m model, the results pasted on the console was +2. Do you know of a way wherein when you type the coef in your example the returned coefficient is -2? I think that would be the answer to my question.Thank you.

Comment: @TimQuimpo It's not helpful to refer to a data set I don't have access to. The reason coef returns 2 is because it __only__ returns the gradient.